# convert csv to tsv using Powershell; Import-Csv fails

Tags: powershell, csv

I am having set of *CSV* files in a folder. I want to convert the files into *TSV* file format. I want to use `Powershell` for the same.

I tried using the below script. it is throwing error.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\sampledata" | ForEach-Object { Import-Csv $_.FullName | Export-Csv {$_.Name} -Delimiter "`t" -Encoding UTF8 }
```

I am getting errors similar to below:

> Import-Csv : The member "1" is already present. At line:8 char:72
>   + ... Desktop\sampledata" | ForEach-Object { Import-Csv $_.FullName | Expor ...
>   +                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Csv], ExtendedTypeSystemException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AlreadyPresentPSMemberInfoInternalCollectionAdd,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCs

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: `{$_.Name}` is a script block. Remove `{` and `}` or use `(Join-Path 'c:\somewhere' $_.Name)`

Comment: yes. I removed it. Still facing the same issue. I think it is something related to `Import-csv`

Comment: Apparently your CSV file has a duplicate field name.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I chose the corresponding answer also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indecated same value exist in the cells in first line of that csv file . It is a normal behavior of command import-csv .

You can find that CSV out .

As a workaround , you may specify the table header with parameter "-Header":

```
Import-Csv xxx.csv -Header a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>As of this writing, the question contains an additional, incidental mistake: `{$_.Name}` is used to specify the output filename: however, `{$_.Name}` is a *script block* that in a *string context* evaluates to its *literal* contents, i.e., *literal* `$_.Name`. By contrast, the intent is to specify the `Name` property of the current pipeline object (`$_`) as the filename: `$_.Name` by itself will do - no quoting or other qualification is needed (although `"$($_.Name)"` too would work, inside a double-quoted string).</sup>

To complement [Elton Ji - MSFT's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39927731/45375):

<sup>Note: The following applies analogously to `Import-Csv`'s in-memory counterpart, [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv).</sup>

The error message you're getting (`member "<name>" is already present`) tells you that ***duplicate values* exist in the input CSV file's *1st line*** (as [woxxom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) also notes in a comment on the question).

**[`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) expects an input file to start with a *header row***, i.e it expects the *first* line (row) to contain ***column names***, with the subsequent rows containing the *data*.

- These column names become the *properties* (members) of the objects ([`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) instances) that PowerShell constructs from the data rows, and given that an object (class) cannot have multiple properties with the same name, **duplicate column names aren't allowed**.

It sounds like **your input file is *missing* such a header row**, which caused the first *data* row to be interpreted as the header row, and because it happened to contain duplicate values, the command broke.

If a header row is missing, you can make up for that with the **`-Header`** parameter, which allows you to **specify column names ad-hoc**, with `Import-Csv -Header <colName1>, <colName2>, ...`.

- If you specify *fewer* column names than data columns, the extra columns are *ignored*.
- If you specify *more* column names than data columns, additional properties *are* created, but they'll have value `$null`.
- As of PowerShell 7.3.3, there is *no* way to let PowerShell create headers for you *automatically*. See the feature request in [GitHub issue #19334](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19334).

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\ -Filter "*.csv" | foreach{(Import-Csv $_.FullName -Delimiter ";") | export-csv $_.FullName -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t" -Encoding UTF8}
```

Comment: Except for changing the input delimiter to `;` and adding `-NoTypeInformation` - neither of which the OP asked for - your solution is essentially the same as what the OP himself tried.
Note that even if the input delimiter had been a problem, it wouldn't have caused the symptom described by the OP.